# How to have backup URL show if the JSON data is undefined?

Tags: reactjs

```
const SearchResults = ({ artists }) => (
  <div className="search-results">
    {artists.map(val => (
      <a href="# " key={uniqid()}>
        <h3>{val.name}</h3>
        <img
          className="box-img"
          src={
            val.images[0].url
              ? val.images[0].url
              : 'https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_images.asp'
          }
          alt=""
        />
      </a>
    ))}
  </div>
);
```

I have an API call going to Spotify to get a list of Artist. When the results all have an image there is no problem but if they don't, React just returns undefined and I can't figure out how to have the placeholder image show.

Comment: That's because that's not a valid image source. An ASP.NET page is not an image...

Comment: @Li357 - not sure about asp.net but I serve up GIF/JPG/PNG files in PHP by just sending the appropriate content header and file content.  The url ends in `.php` ...

Comment: @ivanivan But here, it's a w3schools link to an ASP.NET page with no separate headers. Nothing else in the provided code points to the error the OP described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply have a bare png default image for this in your project, then import it and use it when no image is returned from spotify, something like:

```
import defaultArtistImage from './myProject/assets/images/defaultArtistImage.png';
...
const SearchResults = ({ artists }) => (
  <div className="search-results">
    {artists.map(val => (
      <a href="# " key={uniqid()}>
        <h3>{val.name}</h3>
        <img
          className="box-img"
          src={
            val.images.length !== 0
              ? val.images[0].url
              : defaultArtistImage
          }
          alt=""
        />
      </a>
    ))}
  </div>
);
```

this is simpler than retrieving the image from an external server. Also, doing `val.images[0].url` can give you an error if `.images` it's an empty array

Comment: Thank you so much, I don't know why I didn't think of this.